# Extract responseStatus from Response using Network.Wreq

Tags: haskell, ghci

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Network.Wreq
import Data.ByteString.Lazy
import Control.Lens

totalResponse :: IO (Response ByteString)
totalResponse =  response

status :: Status
status =  response ^. responseStatus

response = get "url"
```

which gives

```
getRequest.hs:10:23: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Response body0’
                     with ‘IO (Response ByteString)’
      Expected type: Getting Status (IO (Response ByteString)) Status
        Actual type: (Status -> Const Status Status)
                     -> Response body0 -> Const Status (Response body0)
    • In the second argument of ‘(^.)’, namely ‘responseStatus’
      In the expression: response ^. responseStatus
      In an equation for ‘status’: status = response ^. responseStatus
```

when I look for

```
:type response ^. responseStatus
```

in `ghci` it gives

```
response ^. responseStatus :: Status
```

I'm completely new to Haskell.

Comment: `response` has type `IO (Response ByteString)`, but `responseStatus` is a lens that operates on a value of type `Response ByteString`.

Comment: If you are completely new to haskell, I would recommend you to learn the basics before trying out a library like wreq which has a lensy API. It would save you a lot of time/frustration in the long run.

Comment: Thank you Alexis King & Sibi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments above pointed out, it is probably a good idea to learn Haskell before using more complex libraries. As stated, you have a type mismatch in your code. `response` is not a value as you might think, but a monad. If you want to get the status code of your response you could try this:

```
status :: IO Status
status = do
  resp <- get "url" -- This is how the value returned by get is obtained.
  return (resp ^. responseStatus)
```

Note that everything is done inside the IO monad, which is the way Haskell has to deal with IO side-effects.